# Postgresql SELECT without hardcoding item

Tags: sql, postgresql, prepared-statement, postgresql-9.1, angularjs-1.5

I have a simple PostgreSql query that looks like:

```js
$params = array();

if ($audienceId === x) {
  // all teachers
  $pullRecipients = $db -> prepare(
    "SELECT email FROM app.employees WHERE emp_cat_id = 1 AND active is true");
}

$pullRecipients -> execute($params);
```

I'm running the queries based on a drop down select, so that if for example the user selects `TEACHERS`, the above query is run. How can I select for instance the `emp_cat_id` or even the category name `TEACHERS` without hard coding them in the query?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php add array with values and change `1` to question mark

Comment: Does that mean I have to alter the database to work with the arrays? Because the list already exists in the drop down, I thought there'd be an easier fix.

Comment: No, you don't have to change your DB. The Array would contain all possible `emp_cat_id` values. You could choose one of them with the drop down select and bind it to your query as described in the manual.

Comment: what's your `$db->execute` statement?..

Comment: Sorry (edited). This is the execute `$pullRecipients->execute($params);`

Answer (score 0):

change statement to something like

```
SELECT email
FROM app.employees
WHERE emp_cat_id = ? AND active IS true
```

and make sure your `$params` is equal to something like `array($POST["drop-down_value])`

and if you want to allow text value - use join, something like:

```
SELECT email
FROM app.employees
WHERE emp_cat_id = (SELECT id FROM emp_cat WHERE name = ?)
  AND active IS true
```